# Identify vectors with same value in one column with numpy in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a large 2d array of vectors. I want to split this array into several arrays according to one of the vectors' elements or dimensions. I would like to receive one such small array if the values along this column are consecutively identical. For example considering the third dimension or column:

```
orig = np.array([[1, 2, 3], 
                 [3, 4, 3], 
                 [5, 6, 4], 
                 [7, 8, 4], 
                 [9, 0, 4], 
                 [8, 7, 3], 
                 [6, 5, 3]])
```

I want to turn into three arrays consisting of rows 1,2 and 3,4,5 and 6,7:

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 3]])

>>> b
array([[5, 6, 4],
       [7, 8, 4],
       [9, 0, 4]])

>>> c
array([[8, 7, 3],
       [6, 5, 3]])
```

I'm new to python and numpy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Mat

Edit: I reformatted the arrays to clarify the problem

Comment: can you print the first few rows of your array and display it here?

Comment: It's very high-dimensional (about 900dims), that's why I tried to narrow it down to the example I displayed (so badly formatted, I'm sorry). What information exactly would you need to help me?

Comment: can you print the few first dimensions and the few first rows? do you have one single numpy.ndarray or multiple arrays? do you have a numpy matrix instead?

Comment: should rows 1 and 2 be grouped with rows 6 and 7 since x3 = 3 for all of them?

Comment: I would like 1,2 and 6,7 not be grouped together

Comment: and I have one numpy.ndarray

Comment: @Mathew I have tried to improve the terminology so that it's easier to find for other people with the same problem. I'm not sure I've done the best job but I think the previous use of 'dimension' was a little unclear in this context, or at least it was to me!

Comment: @MrE - sure! I corrected one bit, I hope it is clear now. The examples should clarify to any reader who uses different terminology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`np.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
>>> a, b, c = np.split(orig, np.where(orig[:-1, 2] != orig[1:, 2])[0]+1)

>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
>>> b
array([[1, 2, 4],
       [1, 2, 4],
       [1, 2, 4]])
>>> c
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: Thank you all! This looks very elegant

Answer (score 0):

Nothing fancy here, but this good old-fashioned loop should do the trick

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], 
              [1, 2, 3], 
              [1, 2, 4], 
              [1, 2, 4], 
              [1, 2, 4], 
              [1, 2, 3], 
              [1, 2, 3]])
groups = []
rows = a[0]
prev = a[0][-1] # here i assume that the grouping is based on the last column, change the index accordingly if that is not the case.
for row in a[1:]:
    if row[-1] == prev:
        rows = np.vstack((rows, row))
    else:
        groups.append(rows)
        rows = [row]
    prev = row[-1]
groups.append(rows)

print groups

## [array([[1, 2, 3],
##         [1, 2, 3]]),
##  array([[1, 2, 4],
##         [1, 2, 4],
##         [1, 2, 4]]),
##  array([[1, 2, 3],
##         [1, 2, 3]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

if `a` looks like this:

```
array([[1, 1, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 2, 4],
       [4, 1, 2, 4],
       [5, 1, 2, 4],
       [6, 1, 2, 3],
       [7, 1, 2, 3]])
```

than this

```
col = a[:, -1]
indices = np.where(col[:-1] != col[1:])[0] + 1
indices = np.concatenate(([0], indices, [len(a)]))
res = [a[start:end] for start, end in zip(indices[:-1], indices[1:])]
print(res)
```

results in:

```
[array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]]), array([[1, 2, 4],
       [1, 2, 4],
       [1, 2, 4]]), array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])]
```

Update: `np.split()` is much nicer. No need to add first and last index:

```
col = a[:, -1]
indices = np.where(col[:-1] != col[1:])[0] + 1
res = np.split(a, indices)
```

Comment: `col[:-1] - col[1:] != 0` is much more natural without the unneeded numerical subtraction: `col[:-1] != col[1:]`. Furthermore, when you `concatenate()`, there is no need for creating intermediate NumPy arrays: `concatenate([0], indices, [len(a)])` is sufficient. Otherwise, yes, the `split()` from Jaime's answer is best. :)